# Deleting one object at a time every 5 seconds Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem with my cocos2d game. I am trying to delete a projectile shot by an enemy every 5 seconds (each projectile is supposed to have a lifetime of 5 seconds), but I cannot figure out how to do it. I get the error of

```
Assertion failure in -[CCTimer initWithTarget:selector:interval:]
```

Here is my code:

```
-(void)projectileShooting:(ccTime)dt
{
    [self schedule:@selector(projectileShooting:) interval:2.5];
    projcount++;
    if([proj count] <= 15 ){
        if(enemy1.position.y < 320){
            v = ccp(player.position.x,player.position.y);
            for(CCSprite *enemies in enemy){
            CCSprite * projectilebullet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Projectile.png"];
            [proj addObject:projectilebullet];
            [self addChild:projectilebullet];
            CGPoint MyVector = ccpSub(enemies.position,player.position );
            MyVector = ccpNormalize(MyVector);
            MyVector = ccpMult(MyVector, enemies.contentSize.width/2);
            MyVector = ccpMult(MyVector,-1);
            projectilebullet.position = ccpAdd(enemies.position, MyVector);
            for(CCSprite *projectile in proj){
                [self schedule:@selector (deleteprojectile:projectile:) interval:5];
            }
        }
    }
}

for(CCSprite *enem2 in enemytwo)
{
    if(  [proj count] <= 15){
        CCSprite * projectilebull = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Projectile.png"];
        CGPoint MyVector = ccpSub(enem2.position,player.position );
        MyVector = ccpNormalize(MyVector);
        MyVector = ccpMult(MyVector, enem2.contentSize.width/2+10);
        MyVector = ccpMult(MyVector,-1);
        projectilebull.position = ccpAdd(enem2.position, MyVector);
        [self addChild:projectilebull];
        [proj addObject:projectilebull];
        for(CCSprite *projectile in proj){
        }
    }
}



}

-(void)deleteprojectile:(CCSprite *)protime:(ccTime)dt{
    NSMutableArray *timepro = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [timepro addObject:protime];
    for(CCSprite *objecttime in timepro){
        [proj removeObject:objecttime];
        [self removeChild:objecttime cleanup:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to remove the child nodes in the scheduled method, what does not work exactly? What's the behaviour that you get?

Comment: I get the assertion error of Assertion failure in -[CCTimer initWithTarget:selector:interval:]

Comment: Maybe its the fact that you use the wrong argument name in your selector ? (i.e. projectile instead of protime)

Comment: @giorashc that's right, it should be selector (deleteprojectile:protime:) , you should make this an answer.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Thanks for the confirmation. Wasn't sure about it and could not test it today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack but this is what I use in my program, until I find a more elegant solution.  I have a method in my game layer that I call to remove a node from its parent, like so:

```
-(void)removeNode:(CCNode*)node {
    [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```

And when I want to schedule a node for deletion after a delay, I call it like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeNode:) withObject:node afterDelay:delay];
```

Simple, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change argument name in your selector to **protime** instead of **projectile**. The selector must match the signature defined in you object's class definition.
Your selector was not defined properly and probably the Timer is checking if the object implements the given selector.

I did not have time to test it so thanks to @RamyAlZuhouri for confirming.

Comment: That does not work because there is no protime sprite in the projectileshooting method. I am doing (deleteprojectile:projectile:) to pass in the projectile sprite in the method deleteprojectile. Projectile then gets passed to protime in the deleteprojectile method, so that is not the problem I think.

Comment: @Alexyuiop, it has nothing to do if you have a sprite named projectile or not. Just look at the signature of the method you are trying to call and look at the selector you pass to the schedule method.